# How to change constraints programmatically that is added from storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-storyboard

I have one screen. It will display like below

[image]

Now When User clicked I have an Account and Password(button) it will display like below

[image]

I want to move both views accordingly
I added constraints using storyboard.Now need to change constraints from programming..

Comment: Just create an outlet of the constraint you want to change like you create outlet of UIButton or UILabel.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You need to create an IBOutlet of your constraint.
[image]

Then you set the constant value of your constraint in code:

```
labelWidthConstraint.constant = newValue
```

If you want it animated you can do something like this:

## Swift

```
labelWidthConstraint.constant = newValue
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { 
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

## Objective-C

```
self.labelWidthConstraint.constant = newValue;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{        
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: You should not call `layoutSubviews()`(see docs). Use `layoutIfNeeded()` instead.

Comment: Nilam Pari, I updated the answer to contain an Objective-C example.

Comment: Also, for animation, you don't need the constant to be set inside animation block. Put it outside of the animation block, so animation block has `layoutIfNeeded` method only.

Comment: Would be nice to show example that doesn't use hard coded values - how does the UI look different on a 4s in comparison to a 7s plus?