# UIScrollView with multiple UIView/UIImageView stacked on each other for drawing

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, xcode-storyboard

I can't believe something this easy when I did not use auto-layout is this hard with auto-layout. I put everything in a `contentView` so that it's a simultaneous zoom for both views (`ImageView` and `UIView`). The `UIView` for drawing should be the same size as the `UIImageView` and not bigger. I have this hierarchy at the moment.

```
    UIScrollView
    - ContentView
    -- UIView (For drawing eg, drawView)
    -- UIImage (For showing a background image to draw on)
```

The `drawView` is a view on top of the `imageView`, the problem now is as following:

1. Users can draw out of bounds of the UIImageView. This should only be possible drawing on the `imageView`.
2. Drawings are under the `UIImageView`, while the `drawView` is on top.

Code:

```
var afbeelding: UIImage?

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var drawView: DrawingCanvas!
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

var dag: Dag?

@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    drawView.dag = dag
    
    if let afbeelding = afbeelding {
        imageView.image = afbeelding
    }
    
    scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2
    scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
    scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return contentView
}
```

Images:
[image: ImageFault]
[image: ImageStoryboard]

Could anyone steer me in the right direction?

Comment: If one of the answers worked, can you click the green checkmark to accept it, or leave a comment to get more clarification?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Interface Builder but for your layer order problem I'd try swapping them; perhaps the order in which they're shown is the order in which they're added.

As for drawing outside the bounds, you'd need to look at the documentation for `DrawingCanvas` but perhaps its `clipsToBounds` property will work?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Users can draw out of bounds of the `UIImageView`. This should only be possible drawing on the `imageView`.

It seems like your image view has its [`contentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode) set to `.scaleAspectFit`, but has all 4 sides pinned to the superview. This means that the image view spans the entire `contentView`, but the *image* itself is smaller.

I think the easiest way around this is to get the frame of the actual image using [`AVMakeRect(aspectRatio:insideRect:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/1390116-avmakerect), then adjusting `drawView`'s frame.

```
let rect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: image.size, insideRect: imageView.frame)

/**
 Instead of constraining `drawView`'s edges, use x, y, width, and height.
 This makes setting them easier.
 You'll need to connect your constraints via an @IBOutlet (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40584432/14351818)
 */
drawViewLeftConstraint.constant = rect.origin.x
drawViewTopConstraint.constant = rect.origin.y
drawViewWidthConstraint.constant = rect.width
drawViewHeightConstraint.constant = rect.height
```

> 2. Drawings are under the `UIImageView`, while the `drawView` is on top.

Actually, the image view is on top. The order is lowest -> highest, so just switch them.

[image: The order is reversed]